# I'm asking about google Charts

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

Okay so I'm researching on if Google Charts will be good to be use as an embeddable charting system for a Web Security Portal I'm trying to build for data visualization. However I am very new to this level of intensity and I would like to know is it possible to have Google Charts auto-update with new information from the database in certain areas of said database?

A bit more information if necessary:

The Dashboard I'm trying to build will have 5 different types of Graphs. I need to know if I can get all of those graphs to auto-update with new information based on certain data-tables for visualization?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Five types of charts? You think we can read your mind or something?

Comment: No I just need to know if its possible to have all the charts auto-update without having to change pages. Bar, Pie, Donut, Column, and table charts

Comment: "Google" and "Web Security Portal" sounds a bit contradicting.

Comment: You compose a URL and you get back a chart from Google. When you use AJAX it should be no problem for your webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can all you need to do is simple store your chart data that is the x and y axis data in your database and call the data from the db. That way you can use update the data using simple  update statement then the updated data will be display on the chart. This means at every point in time only the data in your database will be use in ploting